# Android webview with jquery not working

Tags: javascript, android, jquery

i'm trying to combine some code of jquery on my application webview.

i'm saving on my assets folder the files:
1. jquery-1.8.1.js
2. a.js
3. b.js

all those files working together.

im getting html code from server and i'm saving it on file on the sd-card, that file called test.html.

before im saving that html file i do this:

```
HTML = HTML.replace("<HEAD>", "<HEAD>" + "\n" + 
                        "<script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"file:///android_asset/jquery-1.8.1\"></script>" + "\n" +
                        "<script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"file:///android_asset/a.js\"></script>" + "\n" +
                        "<script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"file:///android_asset/b.js\"></script>");
```

in the right order that worked for me on a pc browser.
but on the devide the js files dont work for me at all.

i have set those before to my webview:

```
WebView web_Body=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.forms_webview);

WebSettings webSettings = web_Body.getSettings();
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
web_Body.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
web_Body.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
webSettings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
webSettings.setSupportZoom(true);
```

and than i do this for opening the file:

```
web_Body.loadUrl("/sdcard/temp/test.html");
```

i just want to say again that in pc browser all works fine.

thanks in advance!!

Comment: Have you tried the minified version of jquery? Because there are some limits in the size of js files you can include in a webview.

Comment: did you resolve it? I am facing the same problem :(